# What is in an empty array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I would like to know what element is in an empty array.

I understand that calling `each` on `Array` with a block will iterate though every elements in the `Array` and evaluate the block.

But here is where I get confused:

```
[].each { |e| puts e }
=> []

[].each { |e| puts e.random_method }
=> []
```

It seems that I can call any method on `e` within the `each` block, and the ruby console will always return `[]`. If `e` were a `nil`, should it not raise a missing method error? Any explanations?

Comment: It will raise a missing method error only when the array contains any element. In your example, the call to `puts e.random_method` is never reached.

Comment: How is "If `e` were a `nil`" relevant to your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several things you are mistaken about.

1. `e` is not `nil`. There is no `e`. "I have no wives. Every one of my wives was a space monster." is true. The block does not evaluate at all because there was nothing in the set. `[]`, an empty array, is different from `[nil]`, a one-element array with `nil` as its sole element (when `e` would, indeed, be `nil`, and `e.random_method` would fail). Look at it this way: if `[1, 2].each { .... }` executes the block twice, `[1].each { .... }` once, then `[].each { .... }` executes it zero times, not once with `nil`.
2. `each` returns the original array. `[].each { .... }` returns `[]`. `[1, 2, 3].each { .... }` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. There is no mystery to be solved there - the return value is not relevant to your question. You are wondering about what is output as result of `puts` - and that's not what `[]` is. There is no output of `puts`, because it is executed zero times (see above).

So to answer the titular question - there is nothing in an empty array, that's why we call it "empty" :)

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that life would be far more difficult for us if empty arrays were not treated this way (but still worth living). Btw, I have a friend who also says, "Every one of my wives was a space monster."

Comment: tremendous explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Check following

```
2.0.0-p598 :001 > [].each { |e| puts e } #Here loop is never get executed because array is blank
 => [] 
2.0.0-p598 :002 > [nil].each { |e| puts e * e } #here loop is getting executed once but throws an error 
NoMethodError: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):2:in `each'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/cybage/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

2.0.0-p598 :003 > [1].each { |e| puts e * e } #here you can see loop executed once print '1' and then `each` returns the array itself.
 => 1
 => [1]
```